# Multiple imputation in SPSS: Excessive iterations to converge?

Tags: spss, missing-data, multiple-imputation

I am doing multiple imputation in SPSS 23 to deal with missing data before running hierarchical regressions. I ran Ender's diagnostic macro which calculates [Gelman and Rubin's PSR](http://www.appliedmissingdata.com/macro-programs.html) (potential scale reduction factor). PSR only converges (< 1.05) at 600 iterations and plateaus at 900, still well over 1.0.

My question is if this is a red flag and I have to rethink my imputation model or if I can go ahead with my intended 40 imputations (per Graham, 2007) and set for in-between iterations at 900 or 1000 (!!) provided I can bear computational effort/time.

Some context:
I have two sets of DVs, one set collected at T1 (with IVs/controls), for which my sample size is a little over 400, the second set collected at T2, with only about 155 respondents paired with their T1 data. These are two sets of different measures of same phenomena.

My intention was to do imputation at the item-level [(Gotschall et al, 2012)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00273171.2012.640589), and given the DVs collected at T2 are correlated at T1 (although just moderately), I included them as auxiliary variables (see more on this below), despite their exorbitant missing.

Overall I have 64 variables in my imputation model, including an interaction term and a quadratic term. A handful of binary, all others scale (interval). Variables do not have excessive missing, except the second set of DVs mentioned above. In fact, I am not too far from what would render even pairwise acceptable, according to Newman (2014).

At last, a second question, if indeed this (what seems to me) excessive iterations to convergence signals I should rethink my imputation model. Would it be appropriate to consider the paired T1-T2 respondents a different sample altogether and do a separate multiple imputation procedure there? If this is not acceptable, I have to keep the second set of DVs in the imputation model, so it limits my tweaking imputation model possibilities.

Thanks in advance for any input!